# Solving a System of non-linear recurrence relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations, recursion, nonlinear-system

While evaluating some integrals I came across this system. I know that most of the times systems of non-linear recurrence relations are unsolvable, but looking at the outputs I got for different m it seems to me like a solution exists, just I'm not able to find it.
Here is the problem:

$$ A_m=mA_{m-1}+B_{m-1}$$
$$ B_m=mB_{m-1}-A_{m-1} $$

Comment: $A_m=B_m=0$ for all $m$ looks like a solution.

Comment: Thank you I didnt notice, but I forgot to mention that in my problem I have Initial conditions $A_1=1, B_1=-1$

Comment: You could convert it into a single recurrence to see if that helps you, e.g. $B_{m+1}=(2m+1)B_{m}-(m^2+1)B_{m-1}$. In any way I would try generating functions.

Comment: Thank you. With generating functions I get stuck with a non-homogeneous system of differential equations.

Comment: I see, well one can always try to evaluate first couple terms of the sequence and find on oeis.org, in this case we find [A009454](https://oeis.org/A009454) and [A003703](https://oeis.org/A003703) which match with some simple sign adjustments, both sequences have exponential generating functions $\cos\ln(1+x)$ and $\sin\ln(1+x)$, some formulas are included as well (without proof though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

This recurrence is **linear** and can be written as

$$
\left(\matrix{A_m\\ B_m}\right) = \left(\matrix{m & 1 \\ -1 & m}\right)\left(\matrix{A_{m-1}\\ B_{m-1}}\right)
$$

now $\left(\matrix{m & 1 \\ -1 & m}\right) = T\cdot \Lambda_m\cdot T^{-1}$ with

$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 i & -i \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\ \ \ \text{}\ \ \ \Lambda_m = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 m-i & 0 \\
 0 & m+i \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

so calling now $X_m = T^{-1}\cdot \left(\matrix{A_m\\ B_m}\right)$ we have the recast recurrence

$$
X_m = \Lambda_m\cdot X_{m-1}
$$

with solution

$$
X_m = \left(\prod_{k=1}^m\Lambda_k\right)\cdot X_1
$$

etc.

NOTE

$$
\prod_{k=1}^m\Lambda_k = \left(\matrix{(m-i)!& 0\\ 0&(m+i)!}\right)
$$

This result is not amenable to work with. Using generating functions we follow with

$$
\cases{
A_m x^m = m A_{m-1}x^m + B_{m-1}x^m\\
B_m x^m = -A_{m-1}x^m + m B_{m-1}x^m
}
$$

or

$$
\cases{
A(x) = x(x A(x))'+x B(x) + \phi_A(x)\\
B(x) = -x A(x) + x(x B(x))'+\phi_B(x)
}
$$

them we have

$$
\cases{
B'(x) = \frac{1-x}{x^2}-\frac 1x B(x) + \frac{1}{x^2}\phi_A(x)\\
A'(x) = \frac 1x A(x) + \frac{1-x}{x^2}B(x) + \frac{1}{x^2}\phi_B(x)
}
$$

Here $\phi_A(x), \phi_B(x)$ are initial condition polynomials. Assuming $\phi_A(x) = \phi_B(x) = 0$ we have the solution

$$
\cases{
A(x) = \frac{c_1 e^{-1/x} \cos (\log (x))}{x}-\frac{c_2 e^{-1/x} \sin (\log (x))}{x}\\
B(x) = \frac{c_1 e^{-1/x} \sin (\log (x))}{x}+\frac{c_2 e^{-1/x} \cos (\log(x))}{x}
}
$$

not expandable in series around $x=0$.

Comment: Yes I got a similar solution, but left it since I wasn't able to find a closed form for the product of the matrices. Do you think such a closed form exists or this is the best we can get?

Comment: I also have a tray with MATHEMATICA  and gave an answer quite similar.

Comment: Note that $\Lambda_m$ is diagonal. This makes the answer quite easy to handle.

Comment: Ah ok this is where my method failed,  thank you

Comment: Fixed a notation error.

Comment: when you say $\\(m-i)!$ you mean $\prod_{k=1}^{m} (k-i) $ ?

Comment: Yes. I mean that.

Comment: I would try the use of generating functions. I will include a note indicating this way.

Comment: Great solution. I tried the approach of generating functions but got stuck at the system of differential equations. How did you manage to solve it?